# Multiple Threads Accessing Large Dictionary object in memory - bottleneck?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Quick multithreading question...

I have a single dictionary object in memory containing about 20,000 items. If I have multiple threads attempting to read from this object, would you expect this to create a bottleneck?

NET 3.5 . Dictionary object would be read only

Dictionary is ReadOnly so I'm not concerned about read/writes, only performance.

Comment: FYI, if you are using .NET 4, use...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't create a bottleneck but a dictionary is not thread safe so you might not get the expected results. In .NET 4.0 you could use [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) for this purpose.

If it's a readonly dictionary then it's probably safe to have concurrent readers, just make sure that you fill this dictionary with data in a static constructor to make sure that writing doesn't interfere with reading and it takes place before any thread tries to read.

Answer (score 3):

If all you're doing is reading and not doing any writes to the dictionary then you should be fine.

Thread safety applies more to mutation in this case, so if you're not mutating your dictionary in any way you're good.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what  locking and writing is going on.

If you do not write concurrently, I think it is safe to read w/o locking and then there is no real bottleneck. But there are no clear specs on this.

If you do write (and thus lock), it depends on what else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

`No bottleneck that I can see from reading,` but I have my doubts about using the Enumerator.

**I have not proven this yet,** but instinct tells me multi threaded apps, using the Dictionary Key enumerator *MIGHT* cause some problems...

Comment: If the enumerator is implemented correctly then there will be no problem. One of the guidelines for implementing IEnumerator and IEnumerable is that a copy of the sequence is made and then iterated over.

Comment: That seems like a very bad implementation, as this will duplicate the memory/storage used. Especially when using large Dictionarys or even large keys. Does this seem correct to make a copy for each thread that will be accessing the Dictionary?

Comment: Well those are the guidelines for implementing an IEnumerator/IEnumerable. I didn't make them up and in fact that is how every .NET enumerable is implemented (if I'm not mistaken). Take a look at this article by Brad Adams http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/10/49957.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is that you initialize the dictionary and then it remains read-only, then using a plain dictionary is fine and will have no bottleneck as it is not thread-safe and so there is no thread synchronization overhead.

If you are indeed supporting a read-only pattern, then I would suggest encapsulating your dictionary in a container type class that only supports read operations. Your clients can then not subvert your design intent by "writing" to the dictionary.

Comment: So, if two threads try and do a lookup from the dictionary at the same time then one would not have to wait for the other?

Comment: @Mark That is perfectly correct. A plain dictionary has no thread synchronization, so threads will execute freely without blocking and waiting.

Comment: There must be some kind of contention on the memory read? Or is that negligable?

Comment: @Mark That really goes beyond the realms of your shared data structure, down to the hardware level. That's beyond the scope of your original question.

Answer (score -1):

use this: `System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock`.
create new the dictionary.
lock the "global" location.
assign it.
unlock it.

if it just a datasource try to use the ReadOnly-Property

Comment: I am not the down-voter, but I should point out that `ReaderWriterLock` has about 15x the overhead than a plain old `lock`. So unless the readers significantly outnumber writers *and* the lock is held for a substantial period of time then this type of lock will likely end up *being* the bottleneck. By the way, `ReaderWriterLockSlim` has about 5x the overhead of a `lock`.